# How to do with the string method `[]` in ruby

Tags: ruby

```
2.0.0p247 :069 > str[str.length].class
=> NilClass 
2.0.0p247 :071 > str[str.length, 1].class
=> String 
2.0.0p247 :072 > str[str.length, 2].class
=> String 
2.0.0p247 :073 > str[str.length+ 1, 2].class
=> NilClass
```

The first line returns `NilClass`, while the second line returns `String`. Ruby method `String#[n]` return a single-character string, and `String#[m, n]` returns substrings from the string. Does that means the single-character string is different from the substrings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the code below :

```
s = "abc"
s[s.size] # => nil
s[s.size,1] # => ""
s.size # => 3
```

Documentation of [***`String#[]`***](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D):

> Element Reference — (a) If passed a single index, returns a substring of one character at that index.(b) If passed a start index and a length, returns a substring containing length characters starting at the index.
>
> apply for both the above - if an index is negative, it is counted from the end of the string. For the start and range cases the starting index is just before a character and an index matching the string’s size. ***(c)Additionally, an empty string is returned when the starting index for a character range is at the end of the string.***
>
> (d) Returns nil if the initial index falls outside the string or the length is negative

- Why `s[s.size] # => nil` ?

Because at index `3` there is no character,so returns `nil`.(applying **rule - a**).Rule-a says that,return the character from the specified index if present or `nil` if not found.

- Why `s[s.size,1] # => ""` ?

Because this goes to directly **rule-c**.

- Why `s[s.size+1,1] # => nil` ?

Because **rule-d** says like that.

Said that `nil` is an instance of `Nilclass` and `''` empty string is an instance of String class.Thus what you got,all are valid..

```
s = "abc"
s[s.size].class # => NilClass
s[s.size,1].class # => String
```

Comment: But why `s[s.size + 1, 1] #=> nil` not the empty string, the **rule -b** should applied it.

Comment: @jsvisa from the [docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D):  *"Returns `nil` if the initial index falls outside the string or the length is negative."*

Comment: @stefan but then `s[s.size,1]` should be `nil` as well since `s.size` falls outside the string

Comment: @tihom *"Additionally, an empty string is returned when the starting index for a character range is at the end of the string."*

Comment: @Stefan doesn't that apply to `str[range]` and not `str[start, length] `, I guess not from the results here but this does not sound correct

Comment: @tihom Stefan is correct.. Things are happening as per the documentation.. see my update..

Answer (score 3):

> Does that means the single-character string is different from the substrings?

No. It means that [`String#[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) behaves differently depending on the arguments passed to it.

You are trying to access past the last character of the string.

```
str[str.length]
```

returns `nil` because there is no character there.

[The documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) states:

> Returns `nil` if the initial index falls outside the string or the length is negative.

```
str[-1]
```

returns the last character, and...

```
str[-1].class
```

returns `String`.

Similarly...

```
str[str.length, 1]
```

returns the empty string `""`.

Again, [the documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) states (emphasis mine):

> If passed a `start` index and a `length`, **returns a substring** containing `length` characters starting at the index.

Since there are no more characters past the end of `str`, this substring is empty.